# Xcode and Git issue

Tags: xcode, git

I have some issues with my git repository (corrupted) but still can see and read some of my projects versions. I want to clean it by reinstalling completely git but I need prior to that to save some projects I recorded in git (some versions of 2 projects). I tried to create a new GitHub place and wanted to export those versions with the purpose to retrieve them once I have reinstalled git, but when trying to do a push I get this error: "The local repository is out of date" - Make sure all changes have been pulled form the remote repository and try again. Pull is not working which means I cannot save it on GitHub, it could be because of my corrupted git repository.
How can I copy those git projects and versions somewhere so that I can retrieve them once I have reinstalled git from scratch?

Comment: Phrases like *is not working*, *I tried many things*, and *it appears corrupted* don't tell us enough to help in a meaningful way. Try to narrow your question down to one issue that you can describe more specifically. Tell us what you're trying to do, what you've done, what result you expect, and what actually happened instead, including the exact text of relevant messages.

Comment: If a *repository* (i.e., a database) is corrupted, reinstalling Git (i.e., the program that uses the database) is not going to fix it. The data will remain corrupted. But note that the message about the local repository being behind the remote repository doesn't imply that anything is corrupted. The fact that pull isn't working doesn't mean much unless you say *why* it isn't working.

Comment: When saying it's corrupted is that I miss several months of git versions backup, they disappeared, that's why I wanted to reinstall it from new. I copied each new changes in git but not regularly on GitHub and now when I want to copy them in GitHub I get the message mentioned above. When I do a pull the pull starts but never ends, that's why I cannot push any version to GitHub, really weird so that's why I think git is corrupted and want to reinstall it.